# Does the managerial title of a LoR writter matter?

Tags: recommendation-letter

In the past I have seen students eager to get a recommendation from a proffesor from the upper management like the dean of the faculty. Especially for academic endevours such as grad. school applications. Or similarly a letter from the superindendant of the highschool for undergraduate applications. Would it be relevant that the LoR writer is in the upper management of the university or would the writer be recognized by their academic standing and nothing else. Please note that I am asking this question for student level research oriented applications.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather get a letter from a professor, even a *lowly assistant professor*, who knows you well and can attest to your ability and potential, than I would from a higher level person who may have little experience in what your research area entails. The purpose of such letters is to give the reader an assessment of your likelihood of success. If it can't do that then it will be discounted, no matter the position of the writer.

However, in case the letter is just a general statement of your character and (easily found) accomplishments, then the dean's or superintendent's letter might be useful.

Comment: What if we assume the writer's knowledge of the attendee is invariant?

Comment: I doubt that you can make such an assumption validly or accurately.

Comment: Gee... the dean of the college from which I retired taught me as a graduate student, then hired me to teach about two weeks after my degree was conferred..

Comment: @BobBrown, anecdotal evidence only. But congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

It generally doesn't matter very much with the exception that letters from your assistant professors or postdocs don't mean as much as those of seasoned professors. In general, what letter readers are looking for is someone who (i) has first-hand and extensive knowledge of the applicant's abilities, and (ii) the experience to put their knowledge of the applicant into context so that they can provide a *relative* assessment compared to typical students applying for similar positions.

Point (i) above implies that a letter from someone who did not teach the applicant in some way or other (or had other first-hand experiences with them) is not a suitable letter writer. Since deans and superintendents often do not teach or directly supervise students, they are typically not able to comment on the actual qualification of a candidate. Point (ii) above implies that full professors and deans are not substantially different in their abilities to judge because they will both have seen many examples of letters, how they should read, and what they should cover.

In other words: Find someone with many years of work experience, but ignore the administrative title they have -- it doesn't matter much to the letter reader.

Comment: I get your point. Just for the sake of pointing out, I have seen multiple instances of high administators (even the president of the university) doing research projects with undergrads.

Comment: Yes, it happens. It happens less at the larger universities from which most applications ultimately come. But even then, what matters is the content of the letter and the experience of the letter writer, rather than the title.